# Join comma separated strings in dataframe

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I have a 3000 cell data frame with cells like this:

```
['abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd', 'abcd']
```

I want to join the comma separate string into one line without spaces like this:

```
['abcdabcdabcdabcd']
```

I want to do this for every cell in my data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `join`:

```
print df
                          a
0  [abcd, abcd, abcd, abcd]
1  [abcd, abcd, abcd, abcd]
2  [abcd, abcd, abcd, abcd]

print df['a'].apply(''.join)
0    abcdabcdabcdabcd
1    abcdabcdabcdabcd
2    abcdabcdabcdabcd
Name: a, dtype: object
```